# Weird jQuery functionality on missing table tags around tr

Tags: jquery, html-table

Check out the below html which I haven't wrapped with table tags knowingly:

**html:**

```
<tr class="item1">
    <td>
        <select name="postArrayFormato[]" id="test">
             <option value="frascoG">Frasco 370g</option>
         <option value="frascoC">Frasco 220g</option>
         <option value="sachet">Sachet 200g</option>
         <option value="doypack">Doy/Pack 250g</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="test" value="20" readonly/></td>
</tr>
```

**jquery:**

This works fine with the above html for some reason, which looks weird to me.

**js fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/gM2vX/5/

```
$(function(){
    $("body").on("change","#test",function(){
        $(this).next().val("99");
    });
});
```

The above jquery doesn't work when I add table tags around the tr, which is obvious and it needs the below code:

**js fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/gM2vX/4/

```
$(function(){
    $("body").on("change","#test",function(){
        $(this).parent().next().find("input").val("99");
    });
});
```

But my question why is it working fine in the first case? 
This is not an issue but just need clarity.

Comment: please read the question once again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspect the html of the page. Since you can't have a `tr` that isn't in a table, the browser "fixes" it for you by removing the `tr` and `td` elements, and as a result, the `select` and `input` become siblings:

```
<body style=""> 
    <select name="postArrayFormato[]" id="test">
        <option value="frascoG">Frasco 370g</option>
        <option value="frascoC">Frasco 220g</option>
        <option value="sachet">Sachet 200g</option>
        <option value="doypack">Doy/Pack 250g</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="test" value="20" readonly="">
</body>
```

Comment: great answer appreciated. chrome is smart enough should check with ie :P